# Remove spaces between digits in a string

Tags: algorithm, replace, spaces, digits

original: "I have the M5 2 0 0 and I like it"
intended: "I have the M5200 and I like it"

How would you achieve this as an algoritm or give a code example?
I believe this question is valid in many programming languages so I won't ask it for a specific one.

Comment: Eh, *regular expression*?

Comment: Kevin is right. Please specify as a comment if multiple spaces or tabs shuld be replaced as well.

Comment: You are right, this is unexpected, I was intending spaces, but Kevin's answer gives a solution for tabs also. Thank you, Kevin!

Comment: Replace `/(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)/` with nothing.

Comment: The fact that the question itself could be asked for every language doesn't mean you should just omit it.

Comment: Why all this hatred? Peace, man.

Comment: Don't make it personal; it's meant to improve the quality of questions asked here.

Answer (score 3):

C# sample (replacing with *regular expression*):

```
String original = "I have the M5 2 0 0 and I like it";

String result = Regex.Replace(original, @"\d( *\d*)*\d", 
  (MatchEvaluator) (match => {
    return match.Value.Replace(" ", "");
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

For languages that don't have regular expressions: iterate through the text. If the current letter is a space and the letters surrounding it are digits, then don't add it to the result.

Sample Python implementation:

```
text = "I have the M5 2 0 0 and I like it"
result = []
for i in range(len(text)):
    if i > 0 and i < len(text)-1:
        prev = text[i-1]
        next = text[i+1]
        if text[i] == ' ' and prev.isdigit() and next.isdigit():
            continue
    result.append(text[i])
print "".join(result)
```

Result:

```
I have the M5200 and I like it
```

Comment: text[i] == ' ' will not consider tab spaces

Comment: I didn't know whether the OP meant "the literal space character" or "any whitespace" when he said space. No problem, though - just replace `text[i] == ' '` with `text[i].isspace()` if you want to detect tabs as well.

Comment: I guess I should also point out that this won't remove _multiple_ spaces between digits. ex. the output for `a 1(space)(space)(space)2 b' will be the same as its input. It's not totally clear to me what behavior the OP would like in that case.

Answer (score 2):

For python you can use:

```
import re
line = 'I have the M5 2 0 0 and I like it'
line = re.sub(r'(\d+)\s+(?=\d)',r'\1', line)
print(line)
```

where \1 stands for the first group \d+ and the second group will not be replaced ?=\d because is only used for matching.

Result: I have the M5200 and I like it

Answer (score 1):

A Java solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "I have the M5 231 0 0 and I like it";
    String output = "";
    if ( input.length() > 0 ) {
        output += input.charAt(0);
    }
    for ( int i = 1 ; i < input.length()-1 ; i++ ) {
        if ( Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i-1)) &&
             Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i+1)) &&
             Character.isSpaceChar(input.charAt(i)) ) {
            continue;
        } else {
            output += input.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    if ( input.length() > 1 ) {
        output += input.charAt(input.length() - 1);
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```